# Trouble to save PDF file from a java web service using C#

Tags: java, c#, arrays, pdf, byte

I'm retrieving a PDF file from a web server java, returning a byte array.

Need save the PDF on the local machine using C #, but the file is saved completely in blank, I think it is because of the byte array format is different.

Here is my code:

```
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/pdf";

WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);

string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
responseReader.Close();

byte[] docByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\file.pdf", docByte);
```

Any suggestions on how to save the PDF file normally?

Thank you for listening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ...
Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
using (var stream = File.Create(@"C:\file.pdf"))
{
    webStream.CopyTo(stream);
}
```

Why don't you do it simply with `WebClient` like this?

```
using System.Net;
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(URL, @"C:\file.pdf");
}
```